# Checking if a group of URLs exist and which is the newest one

Tags: php, if-statement

I am getting a soccer page which has a number at the end for each week. /1/ = week 1, /2/ = week 2 and so on. There are 36 weeks in the season. Week 4 just finished, so the URL doesn't exist for weeks 5 and onward yet. Week 5's url will be valid next week, but right now, it gives me 404 errors.

I use the following code to check if the week (page URL) exists or not.

```
$url = 'http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/entry/13191/event-history/4/';
$html = @file_get_html($url);

if($html==FALSE)
{
    echo 'error';
    //and do nothing
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
    //and do some stuff here
}
```

I am looking to get a simple number of which is the newest week. In this case it should be 4, but next week should be 5.

What's the best or quickest way of doing this? I don't want my page to spend ages checking this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should would work, assuming that the URL structure is unchanging.

```
$base = "http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/entry/13191/event-history/";
for($n = 1; $n <= 36; ++$n) {
    if( file_get_html($base. (string) $n) == false ) {
        // if file_get_html returns false, then the most recent week is n - 1 (the week before)
        $most_recent_week = (int) $n - 1;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I just get `Warning: file_get_contents(http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/entry/13191/event-history/5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in simple_html_dom.php on line 70`. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it works... I just added @ to the start of file_get_html to supress the error message. It's supposed to error, but just not show the error message. Thanks!

Comment: Sure no problem, I tested it just now also and I got the desired result 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the following would be more appropriate.

```
$weekNumber = date("W") - offset;
```

Where offset is used to offset the start of the season from the start of the calendar year.

This would revise your URL line to:

```
$url = 'http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/entry/13191/event-history/' . $weekNumber . '/'
```

Comment: In theory this should work, but unfortunately not in my case. I guess I wasn't clear enough. Most Gameweeks are 7 days apart from each other, but odd ones are 4-9 days apart so they will muck up then. This  URL will always go by "gameweeks" rather than "weeks"... They will still have /1/ at the end. You have given me a great idea though because checking each url is very slow. I might just manually type in the 36 deadlines and use something similar to what you've mentioned. Thanks!